# Error response from daemon: experimental session with v1 builder is no longer supported, use builder version v2 (BuildKit) instead

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I try to build a simple docker file and I get the error.

```
Error response from daemon: experimental session with v1 builder is no longer supported, use builder version v2 (BuildKit) instead
```

What's wrong?

The build command I use is as follows.

```
docker build -f .\DockerFile -t helloworld:dev .
```

The docker file is very simple and looks as follows.

```
FROM buildpack-deps:curl AS download-env

RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-assets/primer-dataset/primer-dataset.json
```

The docker version command gives the following output.

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration  0.1.18
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        4484c46d9d
 Built:             Wed Sep 16 17:00:27 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.0-beta1
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       9c15e82
  Built:            Tue Oct 13 18:14:39 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.1
  GitCommit:        c623d1b36f09f8ef6536a057bd658b3aa8632828
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc92
  GitCommit:        ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

And the /etc/docker/daemon.json file is as follows

```
{
    "hosts": [ 
        "unix://",
        "tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
    ],
    "experimental": true,
    "debug": true,
    "metrics-addr": "0.0.0.0:9323" 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is an issue with the Docker Community Edition (i.e. Docker for Desktop). Here's the commit that fixes it: https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/commit/95971a49f97defa51b166211fbd6d44080540a62

In the mean time, you can do one of the following:

1. Downgrade your Docker CE server version (to 19.x.y, I believe), or
2. upgrade your Docker CLI version (to 20.x.y, I believe), or
3. run Docker commands with `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`, or
4. add the following to your `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file:

```json
"features": { "buildkit": true }
```

Once a patch is released, you can upgrade your Docker CE server version and run Docker as before.

Answer (score 0):

I was using [this test script](https://test.docker.com/) as instructed [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-convenience-script/).

Then I replaced the [test script](https://test.docker.com/) with the [get script here](https://get.docker.com/).

Now the engine version is 19.03.13 instead of 20.10.0-beta1.

```
D:\Trials\Devops\Vagrant\vagrant_ubuntu_docker_multiple>docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration  0.1.18
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        4484c46d9d
 Built:             Wed Sep 16 17:00:27 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.13
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       4484c46d9d
  Built:            Wed Sep 16 17:01:06 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
 containerd:
  Version:          1.3.7
  GitCommit:        8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```